# Running react-native app on local iOS device with fastlane match method

Tags: ios, react-native, code-signing, fastlane, code-signing-certificate

I am using fastlane to deploy beta versions of my react-native app to TestFlight.
I followed a tutorial which advise to disable `Automatic Signing` in Xcode and use fastlane `match` method: it is working great. ([Fastlane tutorial](https://medium.com/react-native-training/fastlane-for-react-native-ios-android-app-devops-8ca85bee614e))

What I would like to do now is **debugging my app on a my own local device**:
I tried doing it from Xcode but I am getting this error:
[image: xcode error]

I also installed `ios-deploy` and tried `react-native run-ios --device` command which gives me no error but the app is **not appearing on my device**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this method to your fastfile you can register new devices:

```
desc "Register new devices"
lane :register do
    device_name = prompt(text: "Enter the device name: ")
    device_udid = prompt(text: "Enter the device UDID: ")
    device_hash = {}
    device_hash[device_name] = device_udid
    register_devices(devices: device_hash)
    match(force: true)
  end
```

then run `fastlane register` in the console and add your name (whatever you want) and the UDID of the phone. That should register your device and let you build to it. Hope that helps!